# Multiple wp_query on archive page

Tags: wp-query, filters

In my archive I have tipical loop

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
endif;
```

And in my sidebar I have a plugin widget which also calls new wp_query to display the recent posts.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    apply_filters( 
        'widget_posts_args', 
        array( 
            'posts_per_page' => $number, 
            'no_found_rows' => true, 
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true 
        ) 
    )
);
```

So far so good. But then I need to add filter for my categories to display and custom posts types:

```
function mvp_add_custom_types( $query ) {
    if( is_category() || is_tag() || is_date() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
            'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'mvp_projects'
        ));
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'mvp_add_custom_types' );
```

Which suddenly starting to break the other query. 
How can I use both of this queries with the filter applied to only theme related(the other query is from a plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this sorted, by adding additional contional statement and wrapped OR statements in brackets:

```
function mvp_add_custom_types( $query ) {
    if( ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_date() ) && $query->is_main_query() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
            'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'mvp_projects'
        ));
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'mvp_add_custom_types' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like you need another conditional in your filter. Right now, it filters all content looking for category, tag or date that don't have the nav_menu_item, mvp_projecvts query variable set for post types. Perhaps you could add a filter to check if some variable is set and only filter if the variable exists.

$archive_ok= true;
 then in your filter:
if ($archive_ok) { do stuff }
$archive_ok=false;

It's a clunky solution and I am sure there are better answers, but it might work in a pinch.